# Spring configuration set up : No qualifying bean of type [] found for dependency

Tags: spring, maven, dependency-injection

I am desperate about this problem. I have been looking around for almost a week looking for solutions to my exception : I have been looking on this forum and also on a site giving the inventory of the many possible causes : http://www.baeldung.com/spring-nosuchbeandefinitionexception

Nothing seems to match with my configuration.
I must be missing something.

The source exception is :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [fr.bnp.paiement.persistence.api.idaos.IDaoCompte] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
    ... 15 more
```

If, instead of the component-scan I explicitly give the bean location in the Spring configuration i get the same Exception.

I am wondering if this is not because of the depency chain of my modules in my Maven project :

```
Services --> ServicesAPI
Services --> PersistenceAPI
Persistence --> PersistenceAPI
```

But I am trying to inject a Persistence bean into a Services one. Is it a problem if Services doesn't have a dependency on Persistence but on PersistenceAPI ?
The spring configuration xml files follow the same chain for the import.

```
Services imports ServicesAPI
Services imports PersistenceAPI
Persistence imports PersistenceAPI
```

How can the Service module see the beans in the Persistence module ? Maybe through the PersistenceAPI (which is the type of the Persistence in my injection) ?
With EJB this dependency chain works fine (probably because there are no xml imports to do).

I tried importing Persistence from Services directly but it does not work if I don't change the dependency chain : it just doesn't find the xml file.
Everything would nicely work if I didn't bother splitting API and implementation, but that's what I am trying to achieve.

I am trying to set up a clean Maven multi-module project.
The code is here : https://github.com/ASolidGrasp/springTest.git
Prerequisites to make it work as is : having MySQL installed.

You have the error when running fr.bnp.paiement.service.test.Main.main() in the WSBanqueServices module.

For those who prefer to read the code here :

In WSBanqueServices module \ fr.bnp.paiement.service.test package

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BeanFactory bF = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:springServices.xml");
        IServiceClient iServiceClient = (IServiceClient) bF.getBean("serviceClient");
    }
}
```

In WSBanqueServices module \ fr.bnp.paiement.service.ServiceClient

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ServiceClient implements IServiceClient {

    @Inject
    private IDaoCompte iDaoCompte;
    @Inject
    private IDaoCarte iDaoCarte;

    ...
```

In WSBanqueServices module \ src/main/resources/springServices.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
">
    <import resource="classpath:springServicesAPI.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:springPersistenceAPI.xml" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <context:component-scan base-package="fr.bnp.paiement.service" />

</beans>
```

In WSBanqueServicesAPI module \ src/main/resources/springServicesAPI.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
">

    <import resource="classpath:springEntities.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:springServicesExceptions.xml" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <context:component-scan base-package="fr.bnp.paiement.service.api.iservice" />

</beans>
```

In WSBanquePersistenceAPI module \ src/main/resources/springPersistenceAPI.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
">

    <import resource="classpath:springEntities.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:springPersistenceExceptions.xml" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <context:component-scan base-package="fr.bnp.paiement.persistence.api.idaos" />

</beans>
```

In WSBanquePersistence module \ src/main/resources/springPersistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
">

    <import resource="classpath:springPersistenceAPI.xml" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <...datasource & co + transactional + persistenceContext...>

    <bean
        name="daoCarte"
        class="fr.bnp.paiement.persistence.daos.DaoCarte" />
    <bean
        name="daoCompte"
        class="fr.bnp.paiement.persistence.daos.DaoCompte" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="fr.bnp.paiement.persistence.daos" />

</beans>
```

In WSBanquePersistence module \ fr.bnp.paiement.persistence.daos.DaoCarte

```
@Transactional
@Repository("daoCarte")
public class DaoCarte implements IDaoCarte
{...}
```

In WSBanquePersistence module \ fr.bnp.paiement.persistence.daos.DaoCompte

```
@Repository("daoCompte")
@Transactional
public class DaoCompte implements IDaoCompte
{...}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If you don't post the relevant code nor the exact error message with the stack trace of the exception, we won't be able to help.

Comment: I was thinking the code was too long to read, that it could be better to give the link to my github repo with the projet. Do you really prefer having the code here ? Thank you for your interest in my question.

Comment: The **relevant** code MUST be in the question. That's the rule here. To know what the relevant code is, at least start by posting the complete and exact stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bean is defined, and scanned (not sure why you do both) in `springPersistence.xml`. And this file is not imported, directly or indirectly, by the `springServices.xml` file, that you load in your main class.

Comment: I did both because I thought one might not work but initially there was just the package scanning.

Comment: Hi, I tried importing directly the springPersistence.xml file into the springServices.xml one but it doesn't find it since nobody depends on the Persistence module. If I'd merge API and implementation I wouldn't have this problem I guess but what I am trying to achieve is to keep them separated.
With EJB I don't have this problem.

Comment: If you don't have the class implementing of the DAO interface in your classpath, how could you have a bean that implements the DAO interface?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't uderstand what you mean.
I have DaoCompte implementing IDaoCompte and DaoCarte implementing IDaoCarte. Are you saying that IDaoCarte and IDaoCompte are in the classpath because they are declared to Spring through the <import resource="classpath:springPersistenceAPI.xml" />, while the implementations are not in the classpath because they're not imported ?
What could I do if I want to keep interface and implementation in 2 different modules avoiding anything depending on an implementation ?
Thank you for your patience.

Comment: No. What I mean is that you MUST have the implementation of the beans in the classpath, and you must import the xml file where the DAO beans are scanned or declared. If you have only interfaces in the classpath, there is no actual code to execute.

Comment: I have no idea how to put those implementations in the classpath because I am not really confident with the classpath. Am kind of newbie with those concepts.
Can I do it avoiding to have a dependency on the implementation module ?

Comment: No. That's what you need. Your application depends on that module. It doesn't have to be a compile dependency, but it must at least be a runtime dependency.

Comment: I did that and it works. Thank you @JBNizet. Am less enthusiastic about it than having no dependency at all but that's how Spring works apparently. Somebody told me to put a fabric to achieve some ease if had to change the implementation. Thanks for your help !!